# Transfer Learning of Numerical Data

Tags: transfer-learning

It seems like transfer learning is only applicable to neural networks. Is this a correct assumption?

While I was looking for examples of Transfer Learning, most seemed to be based on image data, audio data, or text data. I was not able to find an example of training a neural network on numerical data.

I want to use transfer learning in this particular scenario: I have a lot of numerical data from an old environment, with binary classification labels, and utilizing this, want to train on a new environment to do the same binary classification.

The dataset would look something like this [image: Sample Table]

Is this possible? What would the model look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like transfer learning is only applicable to neural networks. Is this a correct assumption?

No. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning) page give you pointers of several examples in other methodologies.

> While I was looking for examples of Transfer Learning, most seemed to be based on image data, audio data, or text data. I was not able to find an example of training a neural network on numerical data.

All the cases you say are converted to numerical data. Image and audio usually via sampling, text via one-hot encoding.

> I want to use transfer learning in this particular scenario: I have a lot of numerical data from an old environment, with binary classification labels, and utilizing this, want to train on a new environment to do the same binary classification.

That is not transfer learning. Transfer learning applies when there are a change in the domain (input features) or in the task (output labels).

> The dataset would look something like this Sample Table
> Is this possible? What would the model look like?

For a simple case as the one you present, probably a simple network with one hidden layer will be enough. Train it with original pairs of {features,label} or, if not available, use the current predictor to obtain the label from the features.

Comment: Hi could you take a look here? https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/27687/visualisation-for-mobilenet-feature-extraction